# read and write b64 image data in memory in PHP

Tags: php, memorystream

the aim is to writing a b64 encoded image strring to memory buffer in one file of php and read it in another php . kindly instruct if this can be achieved . if so, kindly give some guidelines . am new to memory streams.

the actual scenario is as follows:

images are being sent on a TCP socket and those needs to be pushed to the browser in real time . the code is working and streaming but the requirement is to do this in memory. currently the socket image is saved in a file and the streaming code reads that file and pushes it to the browser.

hope to have explained the issue adequately .

Comment: so write the socket data to a variable instead of a file...

Comment: but how can that be accessed in another file.

Comment: It can’t. Unless you put it f.e. into the session. (But that way you end up storing the data somewhere again.)

Comment: If it's real-time, why do you need two separate PHP scripts?

Comment: both codes run in an infinite loop. can they be integrated. The socket code listens indefinitely for data and the http push code indefinitely detects for data change.

Comment: I believe there're PHP extensions (which you normally need to install and configure) that allow to share data between PHP processes bypassing the regular session system ([APC](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-add.php), [Shared Memory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) come to my mind) but I haven't really used them (not sure if APC does use RAM instead of disk or if Shared Memory allows reading from other processes). It can be a starting point.